# How run a batch processing in java with netbeans?

Tags: java, xml, batch-file, netbeans, batch-processing

I have a probelm to implement batch processing (jsr352).
I have create a web application in Netbeans, my code is

```
 JobOperator jo = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
                      Properties prova=new Properties();
                              prova.setProperty("t", "uno");
                        long id = jo.start("simplebatchlet", prova);
```

the problem is when I RUN the project, glasfish write thisWarning:   Caught exception executing step: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: Tried but failed to load artifact with id: sampleBatchletsimplebatchlet.xml.

the xml file is

```
<job id="simplebatchlet" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"version="1.0">

<step id="step1">
    <batchlet ref="sampleBatchlet" />
</step></job>
```

the file i have move in NetBeansProjects\Project\META-INF\batch-jobs , 
the code for job is

```
public class SampleBatchlet extends AbstractBatchlet {
@Inject StepContext stepContext;  
@Override
public String process() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
     String source = stepContext.getProperties().getProperty("t");
     File inputFile;
     for(int i=0; i<20;i++)
     {             
     System.out.println(source);
     OutputStream out = null;
     try {             
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Upload\\" + i + ".part" + Integer.toString(i)));
           out.write(2);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {}
    finally {
        if (out != null) 
            out.close();   

    }
     }
    return null;     
    }}
```

what is the problem? 
someone has a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check two things.

1. The `JobOperator#start` method takes the "filename" of the job.xml without filetypesuffix e. g. filename is "this-is-my-job.xml" then you have to give the string "this-is-my-job" as argument to the `JobOperator`
2. Every Batch Artifact (e. g. your Batchlet) needs an referencable EL-Name, to use it in XML-Files like the job.xml. Therefore you have to annotate it with `@javax.inject.Named` . With this annotation your artifact will be given a default EL-Name which is its Classname an first letter to lower case

Excerpt from JavaDoc:

> the batch runtime must search for the specified Job XML as a resource from the META-INF/batch-jobs directory based on the current class loader. Job XML files under META-INF/batch-jobs directory follow a naming convention of "name".xml where "name" is the value of the jobXMLName parameter